# Unit tests for a simple function thats part of a public API

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha

Given I have to write a simple function that essentially just does a http-fetch
 to the given URL but is part of a public API that will be used by thousands.

I have two main questions about the problem:

1. Since this is a public API Im not sure how to handle inproper input. Should I return undefined or throw an error? (I rather throw errors to make it most obvious what types are expected). I've seen other API's however just returning undefined, which to me seems pretty stupid, as surely you dont want to be handling undefined in high level code?

   ```
   function at(_url, _options) {

       if (!_options)
           throw new ReferenceError("No options provided.")

       if (typeof _options !== "[Object object]")
           throw new TypeError("No options provided.")

       if (typeof _url !== "string")
           throw new TypeError("URL must be a string.")

       ...
   ```
2. Is it too much to actually test if each possible inproper input is at hand?
   (I find myself writing the same test code for each function I write and after a while it seemed kind "wrong" to be doing typechecking in JS. Is there a standard for typechecking inside API's in JS?)

   ```
   const expect = require("chai").expect
   const fetchWithOptions = require("./../index")

   describe("me()", () => {
       it("should throw error if no options are provided", () => {            
           expect(() => fetchWithOptions.at("some-url")).to.throw(ReferenceError)
       })

       it("should throw an error if options are not an object", () => {
           expect(() => fetchWithOptions.at("some-url", "string options")).to.throw(TypeError)            
       })

       it("should throw an error if the provided url is not a string", () => {
           expect(() => fetchWithOptions.at(123123, {someOption: "someOption"})).to.throw(TypeError)                        
       })

   })
   ```

Comment: Perhaps this test code is working but the code looks very much like stub code, thus it is off-topic. If you have complete working test code, then please [edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/180411/edit) your post to contain the entire code. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: This is not stub code, its working of course and taken from my actual code base. I only renamed some things to not have the actual name of the api in here. Sorry I hadnt read the guidelines on posting here but "Given I have..." was merely false wording.

Comment: Don't throw, return `undefined`. Every throw you add means the consumer of the API needs to write extra code to handle it.  Don't use prefixed underscores!!  Don't be so type strict, (what if `_url` is an object that has a `toString` method that will return the url when coerced to one). Use default parameters `function at(url, options = {...defaultOptions})`  that way you always have options as an object and it contains the correct data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback thats exactly what I need.  However I have a few questions, dont you want to post as an anwser?

Comment: 1. You say that the consumer must handle each throw, but thats not true if he himself makes sure that he only passes the right types. Isnt the returned undefined a much bigger problem then a thrown error as the consumer might miss the undefined while developing since he only passes correct values.

Comment: 2. Why no underscores? Isnt that personal preference? I use them only as parameters and it helps a lot

Comment: I posted my first question over at stackoverflow because I think its very interesting and would like to see some discussion on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296984/return-undefined-or-throw-error-upon-invalid-function-input

Comment: Why no underscores!!.Prefixed underscores for no reason is noise, noisy source code is bad code. Bad code is not always obvious, but seldom is it alone  Q.E.D. Needless prefixed underscores are a sure sign of more bad code .

Comment: You throw **only** when nothing else can be done to protect irrecoverable state or to maintain security.  99% of throws if you examine them are not needed. You make an arbitrary conclusion  `TypeError("URL must be a string.")` Must it, but not all strings are URL's and not all URL's are strings, and why are you throwing, you are just the messenger between the customer and the native API where thousands of lines of code are waiting to assess the quality of the URL but you have seen fit to ignore it all based on a simple type check. So what do you do when a string that is not a URL happens.

Comment: Okay, you make a good point in that anything could evaluate to a string. I will definetly update that. But in other cases, as string is actually a bad example here, say I need a number, should I throw then? I feel like letting people get away with loose typing will just hurt them in the long run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assuming this function is async, neither. Provide a callback parameter or return a `Promise` (I'd favour Promises personally). This is a more common / understood pattern in JavaScript.
2. Unfortunately no there isn't, it's very much part of the downsides (and beauty) of using a loosely-typed language. If you're concerned about type-safety then you should really take a look at [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org) or equivalents.

With regards to the tests, personally I think covering each error scenario is fine - I do it myself, they're minimal effort and will help catch any regressions.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, much appreciated. Regarding your first point however, I was returning a promise anyway. In this case however I would still be able to either resolve with undefined or throw an error/reject

Comment: @ThatBrianDude rejecting with the relevant error makes the most sense to me, resolving with `undefined` is unintuitive. When a Promise resolves it's *generally* presumed to be successful, if something went wrong I'd expect it to be rejected.

Comment: Okay but what about when invalid types are provided? I guess thats a reason to throw an error isnt it?

Comment: @ThatBrianDude yes, that's a perfectly valid scenario to throw an error.